# Can't install Pyinstaller - alternatives?

Tags: python, anaconda, pyinstaller, py2exe

using Python 3.6.0, Anaconda 4.3.0 at work and can't pip install. I have a basic data entry program that I'd like to roll out, but it's unrealistic unless it's a .exe file. At a previous job, I did this with pyinstaller, but this computer is pretty locked down and I can't install much.

Tried py2exe and got the "ModuleNotFoundError" and sure enough, it looks like it's not in my package library, though I'm not sure it normally is in 4.3.

Do I have any other options that are realistic for a novice?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: then you can try the third one: cx_freeze.

Comment: you can't pip install because you don't have internet handy? you can download the wheel and use install on the wheel file instead.

Comment: It's not that I don't have internet; it's that it is a very secured connection and I can't download anything that isn't on an approved list. My library has the wheel, it looks like, so I'm going to try that out. Thanks! I hadn't heard of that.